# Can't figure out why my form is not updating the values in the database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have a project that is going to have 8 different forms all updating the same 'user' table in my database. I have the user authentication working and it makes a user in the table on my localhost mysql database. However when I start updating the table I keep getting errors such as email is not unique or http errors or ReflectionException in RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php line 57: Internal error: Failed to retrieve the default value. 
I have tried everything, my create works but it makes a new row and doesn't update the existing row which the user is signed in on.

I'm only new to Laravel 5.4 and finished going through all the Laracasts, so I'm absolutely stumped at what to do.

Does anyone have any thoughts or know how to fix it or restructure it better? Please let me know if I have missed anything out. I have been trying to get this working for 2 days.

Basics.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
class Basics extends Model
{
    public $table = "users";

    protected $fillable = [
        'family_name',
        'given_names'
    ];
}
```

BasicsController.php

```
class BasicsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user = \Auth::user();
        return view('/details/basics', compact('user'));
    }
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $basics = Basics::find($id);
        $basics->family_name = $request->input('family_name');
        $basics->given_names = $request->input('given_names');

        $basics->save();

        return redirect("/details/basics");
    }
}
```

basics.blade.php

```
@extends ('layouts/app')

@section ('content')
    {{--Do @includes for all form components with the components file--}}

    @include ('layouts/header')

    <main class="main">
        <form action="/details/basics" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

            <fieldset>
                <label>Family name</label>
                <input type="text" name="family_name" placeholder="Family name" value="{{ old('family_name') }}" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <label>Given names</label>
                <input type="text" name="given_names" placeholder="Given names" value="{{ old('given_names') }}" />
            </fieldset>

            <button type="submit" value="Save" name="save" class="button button-primary button-wide">Save</button>
        </form>
    </main>
@endsection
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Authentication Routes
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LogoutController@destroy');

Route::get('/home', 'DashboardController@index');

Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    $user = Auth::user();

    return view('dashboard', compact('user'));
});

// Eligibility Assessments
Route::get('/assessment/student', 'AssessmentController@index');
Route::post('/assessment/results', 'AssessmentController@store');

// Details
Route::get('/details/basics', 'BasicsController@index');
Route::patch('/details/basics', 'BasicsController@update');
```

Comment: /do you use laravel's `make:auth`? do you have `email` field in the table?

Comment: Yes I use make:auth and there is a email column on the table

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a rule in your post request which will exclude the email field when updating the model. This is why you're getting the email is not unique error. Although you're not posting the email field but still the save method is doing that. Try using post instead of patch. Just for debugging purposes in your Route.php

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work :( I might be doing something wrong. I updated this:

BasicsController.php
`public function update()
    {

        Basics::patch(request(
            [
                'family_name',
                'given_names'
            ]
        ));

        return redirect("/details/basics");
    }`

basics.blade.php

`<main class="main">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

Comment: You left your action attribute empty in the form. In addition to this try to post a form to the controller without performing any database related tasks. Just to check if your form is working correctly or not.

Comment: I left it empty as it showed that in the laravel documentation. I got several errors then ended up at this: `BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2508: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::patch()`

Comment: In your Route.php make the below changes.
Route::post('/details/basics-update', 'BasicsController@update');

In your update function's body which is in BasicController do a print_r($request->all());

In your form's action attribute add the below value
/details/basics-update

Let me know the result then!

Comment: I get `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161`

Comment: My guess is because there is no update page to route to. It is suppose to update and go back to the same page.
I changed the method back to /details/basics and I get `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233`

Comment: Can you please post your code snippet? So I can have a look at your code.